# Get and reserve an available IP address from a dhcp server to use for my ip camera

Tags: ip-address, c#

I have a c# desktop app.

I have an ip camera and I want to assign a static ipaddress to it. I need to be able to get a 'free/available' ip address from my dhcp server, reserve it and assign it to my ip camera. I can assign the ip address to my camera easily enough. But how do I get an available ip address and reserve it before it is allocated to another device 'plugged' into my network?

I have seen api calls to get client ipaddresses but do not see if I can use it for what I want.

I could ping each ip address on the subnet in order to find if an address is available but that seems inefficient as i would be waiting for a time out from pinging that address. Besides, it would not 'reserve' it.

I hope I making this clear?

NB. I want to assign a static ip address to my ip camera. I have the sdk to do that. It is just that I need to assign a free ip address that is on the same subnet

Comment: Just configure the DHCP server. What does your "c# desktop app" or your sdk have to do with anything?

Comment: Agree with the answers here already, but to be a little more helpful, I'll suggest that you adjust your DHCP scope so there's a block of addresses you can assign statically for your subnet. Ex: For the given network 192.168.1.0/24, set DHCP to only use .100-.254 for it's pool and you could statically assign .1-.99. (And yes, .1 is probably already the gateway.)

Comment: I think what you need is the camera to tell you what the IP address is that it got from DHCP rather than your C# app try to assign it.  Otherwise you should set up your c# app to take an IP address to assign to the camera and whatever the user enters in you can check with a ping to test if IP might be taken already.  In any case, you should not assign static IP's in dynamic space.  By the way, your question is off topic for serverfault.

Comment: @MichaelHampton HI, thanks for your comment. My goal is that my software can always find the camera.  If i know what ip address it is on then I can 'discover' it. I know I could use uPnP but i wanted to explore this other option. Thanks

Comment: @MattH Hi, yes, that is what I am currently doing but I wanted to try to elimnate the User having to type in the ip address as it may not be something they are familiar with

Comment: @MattH but good comments :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't get a 'free/available' addresses list from DHCP server, it simple have no protocol to inform you. It can give you one IP from its pool.

May I suggest to go to the roots and read [some about DHCP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Host_Configuration_Protocol), at least Overview?

The best thing you can do is to set a static DHCP reservation via your DHCP server configuration so every time your camera ask for an IP it will get the same IP, and then set that IP in your app.

I also suggest you to have some "static reservation" range within your DHCP range. Say, DHCP will work with 192.168.100.0...255 IPs, take a good habbit to let it use IPs not from .1 octet, but from, say, .32 instead. This way, you may static assign IP in DHCP within .2-.31 range (I used to use .1 for the router itself) so it will not cross with dynamic IP range. Or you may simple set up static IP within the same .2-.31 range via camera control panel and do not bother with DHCP reservation.

Answer (score 4):

DHCP does not support this. Either your camera will need to support running a DHCP client, or your software will need to ask the user for the static ip that should get assigned to the camera. They may need to reach out to their network admin to find out the proper address.

Comment: Hi, with evberones comments (I posted similar question on StackOverFlow) and yours and @Alexander's I have my answer.  It cannot be done and I need a different approach.  I did not think it could be done but I did not know for sure.  I am going to 'tick' Alexander as he is answer is the same as yours but he gave a bit more info.  Thanks though :)